# unable to run types-react-codemod as it's being installed incorrectly

Tags: node.js, reactjs

We have a project that uses typescript and we decided to update to react 18.
For some reason trying to run a codemod we ran into some odd issues while running with npx, installing the package globally and trying to run it has the same issue.
Using Node v14.5.0, I'm not sure if it matters.

```
npx types-react-codemod preset-18 ./                                                              
types-react-codemod <codemod> <paths...>

Positionals:
  codemod [string] [required] [choices: "context-any", "deprecated-react-child",
     "deprecated-react-text", "deprecated-react-type", "deprecated-sfc-element",
                             "deprecated-sfc", "deprecated-stateless-component",
         "deprecated-void-function-component", "implicit-children", "preset-18",
                                        "preset-19", "useCallback-implicit-any"]
  paths                                                      [string] [required]

Options:
  --version         Show version number                                [boolean]
  --help            Show help                                          [boolean]
  --dry                                               [boolean] [default: false]
  --ignore-pattern                      [string] [default: "**/node_modules/**"]
  --verbose                                           [boolean] [default: false]

Examples:
  types-react-codemod preset-18 ./          Ignores `node_modules` and `build`
  --ignore-pattern                          folders
  "**/{node_modules,build}/**"

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/Users/valoster/Projects/px-ui/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/chalk/source/node_modules/' imported from /Users/valoster/Projects/px-ui/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js
    at packageMainResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:440:9)
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:581:14)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:633:14)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:726:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:82:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:226:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```